# R: min() function returns not correct answer

Tags: r

i have "a" that is

---

[1] "12.5" "12.7" "13.0" "9.6"  "9.8"  "11.5" "9.5"  "11.2" "10.2" "11.1" "9.7"

---

[12] "9.6"  "9.3"  "11.0" "13.5" "9.3"  "10.6" "9.9"  "12.0" "11.3" "12.6" "13.1"

---

[23] "10.7" "11.2" "9.9"  "9.7"  "9.2"  "14.2" "10.6" "10.8" "10.1" "12.6" "12.7"

---

[34] "7.4"  "12.9" "10.1" "12.9" "11.0" "11.7" "10.6" "8.4"  "11.7" "11.0" "10.8"

---

[45] "12.6"

---

and my min(a) returns [1] "10.1"

I can not understand where is mistake

Comment: Are these values strings?

Comment: try `min(as.numeric(a))`

Comment: The problem (if it isn't clear to you by now) is that alphabetical order of strings is different from the numerical order of the corresponding numbers

Comment: I don't think that the downvotes are justified. The source of the problem is clear enough for any programmer who is used to difficulties traceable to numbers vs. their string representation, but for someone coming to R from a stats background this behavior is mystifying the first time you see it. Furthermore (and somewhat surprisingly) this question is not an obvious duplicate on the R tag. I wanted to close it as a duplicate but didn't find a close match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this data frame `dat`.

```
dat
#    x.num x.chr x.fac
# 1    9.1   9.1   9.1
# 2    9.3   9.3   9.3
# 3    9.5   9.5   9.5
# 4    9.7   9.7   9.7
# 5    9.9   9.9   9.9
# 6   10.1  10.1  10.1
# 7   10.3  10.3  10.3
# 8   10.5  10.5  10.5
# 9   10.7  10.7  10.7
# 10  10.9  10.9  10.9
# 11  11.1  11.1  11.1
```

The columns look similar, but actually they aren't, which is revealed by examining it's `str`ucture.

```
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 21 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ x.num: num  9.1 9.2 9.3 9.4 9.5 9.6 9.7 9.8 9.9 10 ...
# $ x.chr: chr  "9.1" "9.2" "9.3" "9.4" ...
# $ x.fac: Factor w/ 21 levels "9.4","9.9","9.8",..: 16 13 18 1 21 11 8 3 2 6 ...
```

Sorting of numerical vectors such as `x.num` happens numerical, whereas sorting of character vectors such as `x.chr` happens alphabetical.

```
sort(c(10.1, 9.1))
# [1]  9.1 10.1

sort(c("10.1", "9.1"))
# [1] "10.1" "9.1"
```

The `min`imum of numeric vectors is straightforward.

```
with(dat, min(x.num))
# [1] 9.1
```

To get the `min`imum of **character** vectors according to its numeric value you may use `as.numeric`.

```
with(dat, min(x.chr))
# [1] "10.1"
with(dat, min(as.numeric(x.chr)))
# [1] 9.1
```

A third type are **factor** vectors which need an extra step. Just `as.numeric` would yield the minimum level of a factor which is `1`,

```
with(dat, min(x.fac))
# Error in Summary.factor(c(7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L : 
#                             ‘min’ not meaningful for factors
with(dat, min(as.numeric(x.fac)))
# [1] 1
```

while the information actually is stored in the factor `levels`.

```
with(dat, min(as.numeric(levels(x.fac))[x.fac]))
# [1] 9.1
## or
with(dat, min(as.numeric(as.character(x.fac))))
# [1] 9.1
```

---

*Example data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(x.num = c(9.1, 9.3, 9.5, 9.7, 9.9, 10.1, 10.3, 
10.5, 10.7, 10.9, 11.1), x.chr = c("9.1", "9.3", "9.5", "9.7", 
"9.9", "10.1", "10.3", "10.5", "10.7", "10.9", "11.1"), x.fac = structure(c(7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("10.1", 
"10.3", "10.5", "10.7", "10.9", "11.1", "9.1", "9.3", "9.5", 
"9.7", "9.9"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Like it says in the comments, your `min()` *does* return the correct answer. However, it is not the answer you are looking for. It seems as though your data is formatted as *strings*, and as such it returns the lowest numbered combination of letters.

First you need to convert your data to numeric. One of these method is to use `as.numeric(data)`, which converts your data to type numeric. If you are uncertain what kind of data you have, `str()` will tell you. I hope this helps!